# Show custom diloag on Azure DevOps in browser upon PR completion

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

We want to show our developers a user feedback modal dialog (in browser) upon completion of Pull Request in Azure DevOps. I have tried to Google it and have gone through [Pull Request Workflow Extensibility documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pull-request-status?view=azure-devops) but couldn't find anything suggesting it is possible. Is it even possible to do? If yes, can someone point us to resources\code which can help us implement this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

> We want to show our developers a user feedback modal dialog (in
> browser) upon completion of Pull Request in Azure DevOps.

We usually use [extensibility points](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/reference/targets/overview?view=azure-devops) to extend the UI in Azure Devops Web portal. But if you want to get the user feedback modal dialog (in browser), the `extensibility points` doesn't support this behavior.

The [Web Hooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/services/webhooks?view=azure-devops) in [Service Hooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/overview?view=azure-devops) is the best thing I can imagine to trigger the completion of Pull Request.

[image]

Any time when we complete the PR, it will send a json representation to specified service (The Url which the Http Post will be sent). Then we can combine WebHooks with other service like Azure Functions to do our customization, like [Use Azure Functions to create custom branch policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/create-pr-status-server-with-azure-functions?view=azure-devops). It seems you need to create own Azure Function or website which shows up a dialog if receiving the Http post from Web Hooks.